# Does the rep bonus show up in recent activity?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users, recent-activity

Will the account association reputation bonus show up in my recent activity section as a distinct item?  I cannot check my accounts for the answer because I have not received any rep bonuses on any sites yet.

This question should be of use to future users of Meta who may not have enough rep on any of the sites to get the bonus, and who may wish to know where it will show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonuses do not show.

As for why, I don't believe I have seen an official answer. However, I would guess it has to do with how bonuses are implemented and therefore, they would not be retrievable in the same manner as reputation from voting and acceptance of questions.

Comment: So the only way to know if one's rep bonus has been granted is if one tracks one's rep, and if you see it jump suddenly?

Comment: McWafflestix: that is pretty much it. If your rep has a pretty wild and undocumented swing it is either because of some sort of one-time bonus or you were the subject of a rep recalc.

Comment: @McWafflestix: are you referring to bounties rewarded, or is there some other source of rep I'm not aware of?

Comment: Traples: He is talking about bonuses such as the bonus given for associating accounts together for +100 on each site, and other one time bonuses such as when joining a site you might be gifted 100 extra starting rep